.Net Core 8 Entity Framework (MySQL) DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `MYSQL_BEFORE_DROP_PRIMARY_KEY` Error
I'm created a migration to add a few tables and update one table (add one column). The database is MySQL 8.0.31 and the EF provider is Oracle's MySql.EntityFrameworkCore
The migration was completed sucessfully, but when I run dotnet ef database update I get this error which I can't find online.
For context, this is a brand new project with only two previous migrations.
Error:
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `MYSQL_BEFORE_DROP_PRIMARY_KEY`;
        CREATE PROCEDURE `MYSQL_BEFORE_DROP_PRIMARY_KEY`(IN `SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT` VARCHAR(255), IN `TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT` VARCHAR(255))
        BEGIN
          DECLARE HAS_AUTO_INCREMENT_ID TINYINT(1);
          DECLARE PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(255);
          DECLARE PRIMARY_KEY_TYPE VARCHAR(255);
          DECLARE SQL_EXP VARCHAR(1000);
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          INTO HAS_AUTO_INCREMENT_ID
          FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
          WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (SELECT IFNULL(SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT, SCHEMA()))
            AND `TABLE_NAME` = TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT
            AND `Extra` = 'auto_increment'
            AND `COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI'
            LIMIT 1;
          IF HAS_AUTO_INCREMENT_ID THEN
          SELECT `COLUMN_TYPE`
            INTO PRIMARY_KEY_TYPE
            FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
            WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (SELECT IFNULL(SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT, SCHEMA()))
            AND `TABLE_NAME` = TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT
            AND `COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI'
            LIMIT 1;
          SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
            INTO PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME
            FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
            WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (SELECT IFNULL(SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT, SCHEMA()))
            AND `TABLE_NAME` = TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT
            AND `COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI'
            LIMIT 1;
          SET SQL_EXP = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', (SELECT IFNULL(SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT, SCHEMA())), '`.`', TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT, '` MODIFY COLUMN `', PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME, '` ', PRIMARY_KEY_TYPE, ' NOT NULL;');
          SET @SQL_EXP = SQL_EXP;
          PREPARE SQL_EXP_EXECUTE FROM @SQL_EXP;
          EXECUTE SQL_EXP_EXECUTE;
          DEALLOCATE PREPARE SQL_EXP_EXECUTE;
          END IF;
        END;
Failed executing DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution.
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Parameter '@SQL_EXP' must be defined.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameterAsync(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex, Boolean execAsync)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParametersAsync(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, Boolean execAsync)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParametersAsync(Boolean execAsync)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.ExecuteAsync(Boolean execAsync)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.ExecuteAsync(Boolean execAsync)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Fatal error encountered during command execution.

How do I fix this issue?

Which MySQL version are you targeting? You should also mention with EF provider you used. EF is an ORM, not a database provider. The snippets you used come from the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql provider though. The error complains about @SQL_EXP which, as far as I can tell, is defined properly here. Pomelo is more popular than Oracle's provider so if migrations didn't work, a lot of people would notice

@PanagiotisKanavos The presence of MySql.Data.MySqlClient in the call stack is a clear giveaway that the OP is using MySql.EntityFrameworkCore. (Pomelo would use MySqlConnector.) The OP should probably just switch to Pomelo.

@BradleyGrainger but the script is Pomelo's.  It's the poster's job to add the necessary information, not wait for an entire day silently. In that case the OP somehow managed to use Pomelo's migration script with Oracle's driver.

@PanagiotisKanavos I haven't compared it line-by-line but it looks incredibly similar to this SQL script in Oracle's EF Core: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/87939c99fdad68b30803e9f4bb115e17cfabb8ce/EFCore/src/Migrations/Internal/MySQLMigrator.cs#L265-L303

Actually, compare the names of the stored procedures: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/87939c99fdad68b30803e9f4bb115e17cfabb8ce/EFCore/src/Migrations/Internal/MySQLMigrator.cs#L267 vs https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/blob/b02dd67febafcb9dc08b803175cf3039d8127804/src/EFCore.MySql/Migrations/Internal/MySqlMigrator.cs#L241. It's not Pomelo (but clearly both these drivers must have a common source for this script).

So Pomelo and Oracle use the same scripts?  Strange, but that leaves an incompatible MySQL version as the culprit. SET @SQL_EXP = SQL_EXP; is valid and so is PREPARE SQL_EXP_EXECUTE FROM @SQL_EXP;. Even the 5.7 docs say PREPARE should use a user variable for scripts constructed at procedure scope. We learned something useful but that doesn't make the question any clearer

Which goes back to comment #1: What's the MySQL version?

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm using MySQL 8.0.31 (on Wamo Server)

@PanagiotisKanavos It could just be a bug in Oracle's code. The call stack has BindParametersAsync and SerializeParameterAsync. I haven't read the code, but what if it's parsing the SQL, assuming that @SQL_EXP is a parameter (not a user-defined variable) and throwing a spurious exception because no parameter with that name was added to MySqlCommand.Parameters?

I.e., the code is using user-defined variables in the SQL but not ensuring that the AllowUserVariables connection string option is set.

@Think_Twice You could try adding AllowUserVariables = true; to your connection string and seeing if that works around the exception.

You can try upgrading to the latest MySql.EntityFrameworkCore  provider (8.0.5 came out 15 days ago) but I'd strongly suggest replacing Oracle's buggy and badly maintained drivers with the truly open source and far more popular Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql  EF provider and the MySqlConnector driver. MySqlConnector and Pomelo fix many of the bugs Oracle refused to fix. The Pomelo maintainers respond and fix bugs quickly. Oracle releases a version only when a new MySQL version comes out.

@Think_Twice which MySql.EntityFrameworkCore version are you using? The latest, 8.0.5, was released on July 1, along with the latest MySQL 8 version. Maybe it fixes the problem but you should really, really consider replacing this with Pomelo and avoid such problems to begin with. Oracle will never offer the same support to .NET, a competitor to its Java platform. Nor will it support MySQL as much as it supports its paid cash-cow database.

I used MySql.EntityFrameworkCore and had same problem. When I replaced it on Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql all migrations accepted fine. I recommend use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, it don't need a lot of change after migration from MySql.EntityFrameworkCore, little bit differs connection and thats all.
